# Join Table issue with rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, activerecord

I have a Color model:

```
class Color < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sector
```

A sector model:

```
class Sector < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :colors
```

I created a join table like:

```
class CreateJoinTableColorSector < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_join_table :color, :sectors do |t|
      t.index %i[color_id sector_id]
      t.index %i[sector_id colore_id]
   end
 end
end
```

Now I want to get all the Colors who belongs to a specific sector. I tried :

```
Color.joins(:sectors).where({ sector: sector })
```

But it returns me an error → `uninitialized constant Color::Sectors`

Comment: What's `ColorScheme`? There's a typo in `colore_id`, and `has_many :color` (should be plural). Did you update the models after running the migrations? Did you create the model for the join table? Why are you using a join table in a one-to-many relationship?

Comment: I fixed the typos I don't a model for the join table should I? I try to get all the Colors who belongs to a specific sector, i thought join was the way to go

Comment: I think you're fine without it. See your relationships, they're "upside-down", one is in plural while it should be in singular (Color), the other way is in singular when it should be plural (Sector). `Color.where(sector_id: sector.id)` might work.

Comment: try `Color.joins(:sector)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `Color` model like:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: colors
#
#  id           :integer          not null, primary key
#  created_at   :datetime         not null
#  updated_at   :datetime         not null
#
class Color < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :color_sectors
  has_many :sectors, through: :color_sectors  
end
```

And a `Sector` model like:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: sectors
#
#  id           :integer          not null, primary key
#  created_at   :datetime         not null
#  updated_at   :datetime         not null
#
class Sector < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :color_sectors
  has_many :colors, through: :color_sectors
end
```

Then you create your `ColorSector` model like:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: color_sectors
#
#  id           :integer          not null, primary key
#  color_id     :integer
#  sector_id    :integer
#  created_at   :datetime         not null
#  updated_at   :datetime         not null
#
class ColorSector < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :color
  belongs_to :sector
end
```

And when you have an `@color` and you want to get all the associated `Sector` records, you can do:

```
@color.sectors
```

And when you have an `@sector` and you want to get all the associated `Color` records, you can do:

```
@sector.colors
```

If you want to associate a `@color` with a `@sector`, then you do:

```
@sector.colors << @color
```

This, and more, is all covered thoroughly in the [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Comment: Do i need to create the `ColorSector` model, I tought i can do it without it

Comment: Why wouldn't you have a `ColorSector` model? Rails is all about convention and this is the conventional way of doing a m:m association. (You could, I guess, do a HABTM, but I never, ever use that.)

Answer (score 0):

If you need many-to-many relationships, use [has_and_belongs_to_many](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) association